# redux-persist not working in electron app

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, electron, redux-persist

I am trying to use `redux-persist` with my electron app but state doesn't persist. I am unsure what I'm doing wrong. When I CMD+R state is reset. Also state is reset when the fully built app is quit, and then relaunched.

My electron app is made with react + redux and bundled with webpack.

store.js

```
import { createStore, compose, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from '../reducers';
import { persistStore, persistCombineReducers } from 'redux-persist'; //persistReducer
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage'; // defaults to localStorage for web
import autoMergeLevel1 from 'redux-persist/lib/stateReconciler/autoMergeLevel1';

const persistConfig = {
   key            : 'primary',
   storage,
   stateReconciler: autoMergeLevel1
};
const persistedReducer = persistCombineReducers(persistConfig, rootReducer);

const actionSanitizer = (action) => (
  action.type === 'ADD_FILE' && action.libraryEntry ?
    { ...action,
      libraryEntry: {
        artwork: '<<LARGE_ARTWORK_BUFFER>>'
      }
    } : action
);

const composeEnhancers =
  typeof window === 'object' && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__
    ? window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__({
      name          : 'Melo',
      actionSanitizer,
      stateSanitizer: (state) => state.library.files ? {
        ...state, library: {
          files: '<<LONG_LIST_OF_FILES>>'
        }
      } : state
    })
    : compose;

const enhancer = composeEnhancers(
  applyMiddleware(thunk)
);

const configureStore = (initialState) => {
  const store = createStore(persistedReducer, initialState, enhancer);
  const persistor = persistStore(store);
  return { store, persistor };
};

export default configureStore;
```

Each reducer is defined as:

```
import * as constants from '../../constants/settings';

const ACTION_HANDLERS = {
  [constants.SET_ERROR_REPORTING]: (state, { allowReporting }) => {
    return {
      ...state,
      error: {
        allowReporting
      }
    };
  },
  [constants.SET_ERROR_MODAL]: (state, { allowErrorModal }) => {
    return {
      ...state,
      error: {
        allowErrorModal
      }
    };
  },
  [constants.DISABLE_ERROR_REPORTING]: (state) => {
    return {
      ...state,
      error: {
        allowReporting: false
      }
    };
  }
};

export const initialState = {
  error: {
    allowReporting : false,
    allowErrorModal: true
  }
};

const settingsReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  const handler = ACTION_HANDLERS[action.type];

  return handler ? handler(state, action) : state;
};

export default settingsReducer;
```

rootReducer is exported here:

```
import library from './library';
import player from './player';
import view from './view';
import settings from './settings';

export default {
  library,
  player,
  view,
  settings
};
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { BarLoader } from 'react-spinners';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react';
import configureStore from './store';
import MainView from './app';
import './styles/global.scss';

const { store, persistor } = configureStore({});

const loading = <BarLoader color={'#3E8BD3'} size={25}/>;

require('dotenv').config();

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <PersistGate loading={loading} persistor={persistor}>
      <MainView/>
    </PersistGate>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I did post a issue inside `redux-persist` github issues [here](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist/issues/1064). There were a couple threads from a few years ago for this particular issue, but those solutions did not work for me. Thank you for any and all help!

**Update:**
I implemented the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57257204/5965537) in the first answer but I am still seeing the same behavior

Comment: Did ```redux-persist``` work with ```electron``` in ```development```?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was my webpack configuration was incorrect, and I was running an older version of my code that did not have the proper setup. Here are the final files that allowed me to get this to work!

**src/store/index.js**

```
import { createStore, compose, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from '../reducers';
import { persistStore, persistCombineReducers } from 'redux-persist';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';
import autoMergeLevel1 from 'redux-persist/lib/stateReconciler/autoMergeLevel1';
import logger from 'redux-logger';

const persistConfig = {
  key            : 'primary',
  storage,
  stateReconciler: autoMergeLevel1
};
const persistedReducer = persistCombineReducers(persistConfig, rootReducer);

const actionSanitizer = (action) => (
  action.type === 'ADD_FILE' && action.libraryEntry ?
    { ...action,
      libraryEntry: {
        artwork: '<<LARGE_ARTWORK_BUFFER>>'
      }
    } : action
);

const composeEnhancers =
  typeof window === 'object' && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__
    ? window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__({
      name          : 'Melo',
      actionSanitizer,
      stateSanitizer: (state) => state.library.files ? {
        ...state, library: {
          files: '<<LONG_LIST_OF_FILES>>'
        }
      } : state
    })
    : compose;


const middlewares = [thunk, logger];

const enhancer = composeEnhancers(
  applyMiddleware(...middlewares)
);

const reduxStore = createStore(persistedReducer, {}, enhancer);
const persistor = persistStore(reduxStore);
const store = { reduxStore, persistor };

export default store;
```

**src/index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { BarLoader } from 'react-spinners';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react';
import MainView from './app';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import './styles/global.scss';
import store from './store';

const { reduxStore, persistor } = store;

registerServiceWorker();

const loading = <BarLoader color={'#3E8BD3'} size={25}/>;

require('dotenv').config();

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={reduxStore}>
    <PersistGate loading={loading} persistor={persistor}>
      <MainView/>
    </PersistGate>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**src/reducers/index.js**

```
import library from './library';
import player from './player';
import view from './view';
import settings from './settings';

export default {
  library,
  player,
  view,
  settings
};
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

// Config directories
const SRC_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src');
const OUTPUT_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, './build');

// Any directories you will be adding code/files into, need to be
// added to this array so webpack will pick them up
const defaultInclude = [SRC_DIR];


module.exports = {
  entry : `${SRC_DIR}/index.js`,
  mode  : 'development',
  output: {
    path      : OUTPUT_DIR,
    publicPath: path.join('./'),
    filename  : 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(s*)css$/,
        use : [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test   : /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules(?!(\/|\\)js-utils)/,
        loader : 'babel-loader'
      },
      {
        test   : /\.jsx$/,
        exclude: /node_modules(?!(\/|\\)js-utils)/,
        loader : 'babel-loader'
      },
      {
        test   : /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/,
        use    : [{ loader: 'file-loader?name=img/[name]__[hash:base64:5].[ext]' }],
        include: defaultInclude
      },
      {
        test   : /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
        use    : [{ loader: 'file-loader?name=font/[name]__[hash:base64:5].[ext]' }],
        include: defaultInclude
      }
    ]
  },
  target : 'electron-renderer',
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'public/index.html',
      inject  : 'body'
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development')
    })
  ],
  devtool  : 'cheap-source-map',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: OUTPUT_DIR,
    stats      : {
      colors  : true,
      chunks  : false,
      children: false
    },
    before() {
      spawn(
        'electron',
        ['./public/electron.js'],
        { shell: true, env: process.env, stdio: 'inherit' }
      )
        .on('close', code => process.exit(0))
        .on('error', spawnError => console.error(spawnError));
    }
  }
};
```

Thanks to all who helped me!

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: I've written this too fast without enough thought. This is not even to be watched

<strike>I might be wrong, but in my opinion your store should be created once in your `store.js` file.</strike>

Reading this line, I'm guessing you're creating a new store every single time you reload or launch your app which makes you lose the persisted data:

```js
const { store, persistor } = configureStore({});
```

You'd better export your store in your `store.js` file:

```
...

const store = createStore(persistedReducer, initialState, enhancer);
const persistor = persistStore(store);
export {
  store,
  persistor
}
```

and then import your store in your `App.js` file:

```js
import { store, persistor } from './store'
```

hope this helps

Comment: thanks for the help! Unfortunately I still see the same initial state after making these changes. Could this be a problem with my use of stateReconciler: autoMergeLevel1?

Comment: @Megan I've tested your case in an electron app (with a simpler reducer). I get it to work well. If you add a logger middleware can you see the rehydration action in the console? Also you can check the `Application` tab in the dev tools and check out if the values are stored in the storage you chose.

Comment: thank you so much for sticking with while I was trying to figure this out! The problem was that my webpack config was actually not rebuilding my code. So my setup was correct, but I was running a older version of my code that was not setup properly! Thank you again so much for your help!